# What are the options for sending legitimate bulk email?

Tags: email, email-server, bulk-action

I've got a new client that wants to send batches of around 1000 emails weekly to their client list (all opt-in recipients).

Previously when I've built something for a client it has been their own mail server.

Can anyone recommend any alternatives to hosting their own mail server?

Google apps seems to have a 500 emails in 24hr limitation.

Google Groups would require recipient sign-up & wouldn't use the clients email address.

Other third party services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are hundreds of services out on the net that are fantastic for this. Here are the ones I've used or currently use and I suggest all of them. Both cost money of course but its not too bad.

[Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/)
I love campaign monitor because It allows me complete freedom with the design very easily.

[Mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) 
Mailchimp has some fantastic analytics information and pretty good design functionality.

Comment: I highly recommend Mailchimp. They've got a great product, and as a bonus, a great sense of humor.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of using a third party service is that they can deal with any CAN-SPAM issues that may arise. My day job is to support a very large integration with a third party email vendor. The integration is very large and we send several million emails a month.

You list is relatively small, so you won't need much to make them go. I'm not that familiar with the smaller vendors, but I have heard good things about both Campaign Monitor and MailChimp. Avoid the larger companies, because they will try to lock you into a yearly contract.

The larger vendors are DREAMmail, YesMail, ExactTarget, GoodMail, Zustek, and several others.

Answer (score 1):

[phplist](http://www.phplist.com) is an open source php based mailout manager. I have used it to send to around 4k addresses. Has a 'double opt-in' system that ensures people who unsubscribe stay unsubscribed.

Comment: Unrelated. He's looking for SMTP relay solutions, not for software to manage mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into some of the larger email contact list providers. There are a number that specialize in taking care of subscribers end to end and give you analytics and the like. Take a look at [Exact Target](http://email.exacttarget.com/), [Vertical Response](http://www.verticalresponse.com/) and maybe [Webmail.us](http://Webmail.us).

Answer (score 0):

As a locally loaded application, I have use [Maillist king](http://www.xequte.com/maillistking/) Successfully for sending thousands of emails.  The pro version contains a built-in smtp server.